# Check data flow anomalies for automated BPMN tasks

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

I am calling Java implementations from the service tasks in my Camunda BPMN files, which read, modify and set global variables. Thus I have a high risk of data flow anomalies.

**Are there some best practices and tools to help me avoid or detect data flow anomalies as early as possible?** Maybe some way to define the interface of each service task (which variables it requires, modifies, adds)?

---

What I have tried so far:

1) My first attempt was to define clean interfaces for the service tasks by making the Java implementation only work with local variables and use Camunda's Input/Output-Mappings. But I think that becomes too complex for customers to use (especially if a java implementation reads optional global variables).

2) I did find the tool [vPAV](https://github.com/viadee/vPAV), whose [ProcessVariablesModelChecker](https://github.com/viadee/vPAV/blob/master/docs/ProcessVariablesModelChecker.md) looks quite promising. But I do not find a way to tell the tool which global variable is read/modified/set by which Java implementation. (There is a [German blog post covering clean code of variables for Camunda](https://blog.viadee.de/umgang-mit-variablen-in-camunda-prozessen), but it mainly refers to vPAV).

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that only using local variables on ServiceTasks and define a Mapping for each used variable in the bpmn-model would end in a lot mapping activties that aren't really needed. To my mind that approach is not really handsome for developers. As written in my blogpost a good organisation would help but not technically "solve" that problem.

You do not have to tell vPAV which variables are set by a delegate. The approach discovers updates in your implementation and process models on its own.

Do you have a minimal example of a process project (on github?) showing your problem?

Regards,
Matthias